# Kafka Connection to 2 was disconnected before the response was read

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-producer-api

We are getting the below exception in Kafka server.Please let me know why we are getting this issue?
This issue keep on coming in the production environment. kafka version is 2.12-2.3.0

```
rEpoch=Optional[2708]), rds_exception-1=(fetchOffset=0, logStartOffset=0, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[3628]), __consumer_offsets-34=(fetchOffset=0, logStartOffse

t=0, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[3002]), rde_exception-1=(fetchOffset=0, logStartOffset=0, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[3765]), RDE_FLOW.object_

mapper4-6=(fetchOffset=1, logStartOffset=1, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[2676]), __consumer_offsets-16=(fetchOffset=1502, logStartOffset=0, maxBytes=1048576, curr

entLeaderEpoch=Optional[2996]), RDS_FLOW.JsonToRDS-1=(fetchOffset=0, logStartOffset=0, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[3637]), KF_SET_AS_DOWNLOADED_RESC_PROD-13=(fe

tchOffset=704121, logStartOffset=653504, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[2854]), RDS_FLOW.FromMongo-2=(fetchOffset=0, logStartOffset=0, maxBytes=1048576, currentLead

erEpoch=Optional[3596]), RDE_FLOW.getTMBLicenseScript6-3=(fetchOffset=0, logStartOffset=0, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[2711]), __consumer_offsets-5=(fetchOffset=

439993802, logStartOffset=0, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[3743])}, isolationLevel=READ_UNCOMMITTED, toForget=, metadata=(sessionId=1197409999, epoch=INITIAL), rac

kId=) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to 2 was disconnected before the response was read
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.sendAndReceive(NetworkClientUtils.java:100)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherBlockingSend.sendRequest(ReplicaFetcherBlockingSend.scala:107)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.fetchFromLeader(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:197)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.processFetchRequest(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:286)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.$anonfun$maybeFetch$3(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:133)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.$anonfun$maybeFetch$3$adapted(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:132)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:274)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.maybeFetch(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:132)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.doWork(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:114)
        at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:89)
[2020-06-11 13:02:36,970] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Consumer and producer failing with error: "Connection to 0 was disconnected before the response was read"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56209797/consumer-and-producer-failing-with-error-connection-to-0-was-disconnected-befo)

Comment: no this is not actual issue

Comment: What version of Kafka are you running? Please add it to your question

Comment: We are using kafka 2.12-2.3.0

Comment: Did you find a solution for it?